# SQL Server : table variable continues to give null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I am having an issue that keeps giving me grief. I am working on this E-Commerce project and the way that it's set up is to use a table variable to create it to do some comparison functions for a wish list feature I am working on. Pretty much if the best price coming from the `MasterProduct` table is less then the currently stored price, get that value and store that ID.

The issue is that I am always getting a null reference error when I try to use this. I am very new to creating table variables in SQL so I am completely lost as to what to do. Could anyone be able to help me understand how I could fix this issue?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DAL_Wishlist_SelectAllPersonIDByPriceDrop] 
    (@iErrorCode INT OUTPUT) 
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @MasterProductIDTable TABLE 
            ( 
                MasterProductID [int] NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (MasterProductID)
            ) 

    INSERT INTO @MasterProductIDTable (MasterProductID)
        SELECT DISTINCT [MasterProduct].[MasterProductID]
        FROM [dbo].[Wishlist], [dbo].[MasterProduct]
        WHERE [MasterProduct].[MasterProductID] = [Wishlist].[MasterProductID] 
          AND [MasterProduct].[BestPrice] < [Wishlist].[PreviousCost]

    SELECT DISTINCT [Wishlist].[PersonID] 
    FROM [dbo].[Wishlist], @MasterProductIDTable mpt
    WHERE [Wishlist].[MasterProductID] = mpt.MasterProductID

    SELECT @iErrorCode = @@ERROR
GO
```

The stored procedure is rather simple in that it's:

```
private List<Wishlist> _loadAllFromDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    List<Wishlist> list = new List<Wishlist>();

    for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
    {
        list.Add(_loadFromDTRow(index, dt));
    }

    return list;
}

private Wishlist _loadFromDTRow(int row, DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Wishlist wishlist = new Wishlist();
        wishlist.ID = (int)dt.Rows[row]["ID"];
        wishlist.PersonID = (int)dt.Rows[row]["PersonID"];
        wishlist.MasterProductID = (int)dt.Rows[row]["MasterProductID"];
        wishlist.DateAdded = (DateTime)dt.Rows[row]["DateAdded"];
        wishlist.PreviousCost = (decimal)dt.Rows[row]["PreviousCost"];

        return wishlist;
    }
    else 
        return null;
}
```

And:

```
public List<int> SelectAllPersonIDByPriceDrop()
{
    SqlCommand scmCmdToExecute = new SqlCommand();
    scmCmdToExecute.CommandText = "dbo.[DAL_Wishlist_SelectAllPersonIDByPriceDrop]";
    scmCmdToExecute.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    scmCmdToExecute.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iErrorCode", SqlDbType.Int, 4, ParameterDirection.Output, true, 10, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Proposed, (SqlInt32)0));

    DataTable dt = SqlDB.ExecuteQuery(scmCmdToExecute);

    List<int> masterProductIDList = new List<int>();

    for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
    {
        int masterProductID = (int)dt.Rows[index]["PersonID"];
        masterProductIDList.Add(masterProductID);
    }

    return masterProductIDList;
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: MSSQL not is mysql, ive remove the mysql tag

Comment: A quick note on vocabulary- the stored procedure above uses a "Table Variable" and not a "Temp Table."  There are similarities between these concepts, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: it seems that your sql is returning the @@error variable as output. try SET   @iErrorCode=@@ERROR

Comment: You really should learn to use aliases for your tables and start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for over 25 years now.

Comment: initialize your datatable 'dt' before using it.

Comment: I would change your joins to ANSI INNER JOINS rather than old style joins - see https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input.

The current code is really a legacy coding standard I inherited when I joined up this current position. So if it's something that could be done differently than above that's cool. But I have to stay in this coding standard, otherwise I get question after question about why I didn't follow the coding standards.

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure could be greatly simplified to a single select statement and no table variables. I have no idea what your intention is for @iErrorCode, it is not referenced at all in your code. Also, you need to select ALL the columns you want to use in the code. You are referencing columns in the c# not in your query. I am not sure which table those come from so you will need to add them.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DAL_Wishlist_SelectAllPersonIDByPriceDrop] 
(
    @iErrorCode int OUTPUT
) AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT w.PersonID
    FROM Wishlist w
    JOIN dbo.MasterProduct mp ON mp.MasterProductID = w.MasterProductID 
            AND mp.BestPrice < w.PreviousCost
    GROUP BY w.PersonID;
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. +1

Comment: I used group by instead of distinct but it is hard to know what the OP is really trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks. When I get back to work on Monday I'll try this out to see if this works.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need to worry about an error code with a `select` query, which your procedure can easily be distilled down to:

```
create procedure dbo.dal_Wishlist_SelectAllPersonIDbyPriceDrop as
begin;
  set nocount on;
  select distinct w.PersonId
  from dbo.Wishlist w
    inner join dbo.MasterProduct mp
      on mp.MasterProductID = w.MasterProductID 
  where mp.BestPrice < w.PreviousCost
end;
go
```

or using `exists()`:

```
create procedure dbo.dal_Wishlist_SelectAllPersonIDbyPriceDrop as
begin;
  set nocount on;
  select distinct w.PersonId
  from dbo.Wishlist w
  where exists (
    select 1
    from dbo.MasterProduct mp
    where mp.MasterProductID = w.MasterProductID 
      and mp.BestPrice < w.PreviousCost
    )
end;
go
```

Comment: I like this answer as well. I'll give it a try when I get back to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify where the NULL (specifically) occurs so I suspect this should help:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt = SqlDB.ExecuteQuery(scmCmdToExecute);
```